# how to get check if any key has a substring in a e.Data property in an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I am throwing an exception that has few elements in the e.Data property.

The key of the Data is a string, so to handle this exception I would like to get the first element that contains a code. So I am trying to do that:

```
var myData = e.Data.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Contains("myCode"));
```

Something like that. The problem is that Keys has not this method.

In the MSDN documentation I have seen the it is possible to iterate all the items with a foreach, but I would like to avoid this because it is extra code.

So, is it possible to check if a key in Data has the code and then if it has handle the exception for this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your keys are strings you might need to cast them first because the [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) property is not generic:

```
var myData = e.Data.Keys.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Contains("myCode"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a cleaner trick. Contains() method will do the necessary check, if a valid key exists or not.

```
 if(e.Data.Contains("myCode"))
 {
     // Perform desired action
 }
 else
 {
    // Continue code execution
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but e.Data has not the contains method.

Comment: Isn't e.Data an IDictionary?